# Solving nonhomogeneous differential equations with initial conditions using finite difference method

Tags: differential

[image]

I want to solve equation (1) using the finite difference method employing the initial conditions (eqs. 2-3, 4). The initial condition at z = -2400 nm for every value of r, gives the P(r,z) and will serve as a source for the differential equation that needs to be solved. Any suggestions will be appreciated.

Comment: Can you attempt to enter those equations as latex, as an exercise?

Comment: sorry. this is my first time on stack exchange.  I types these equations in lyx and then could not find how to insert these equations. so inserted the image file.

Comment: Well how about trying to do it as an exercise? If you're going to call yourself "Mathguy", you probably need to learn this don't you? So why not make an attempt?

Comment: thank you for your suggestion. I will repost this using latex (i guess online).